# LinQ query question

Tags: linq

```
var icerikler1 = (from x in data.Tbl_Iceriklers
                  where x.ust_kategori_id == 96
                  select x).OrderByDescending(a => a.ID).Take(4);
```

I have pulled content of the last 4 ,then connect to repeater.I have no problem here.But,I want to be
`ust_kategori_id == 96` of the first two records.
Finally,I want to be  `ust_kategori_id == 95` of the another two records.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean a UNION?

```
var icerikler1 = (from icerik in data.Tbl_Iceriklers
              where icerik.ust_kategori_id == 96
              select icerik).OrderByDescending(a => a.ID).Take(2).Union((from icerik in data.Tbl_Iceriklers
              where icerik.ust_kategori_id == 95
              select icerik).OrderByDescending(a => a.ID).Take(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `ust_kategori_id`, filter out any group besides those with key `95` and `96` and then take 2 of each group with the order you specified:

```
var icerikler1 = data.Tbl_Iceriklers
                     .GroupBy( x=> x.ust_kategori_id)
                     .Where( g=> g.Key == 95 || g.Key == 96)
                     .SelectMany( g=> g.OrderByDescending(a => a.ID).Take(2));
```